# How to pass glue job retry count number as parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue

I have configured glue job to run 3 times if job fails. is there any way to pass that retry count number1, 2 or 3 like that. i am creating glue jobs through terraform and i wanted  to pass the retry count as showed below through default arguments.

```
1 Failed retry = 1 (pass 1 as parameter if attempting first retry)
2 failed retry = 2 (pass 2 as parameter if attempting first retry)
3 failed retry = 3 (pass 3 as parameter if attempting first retry)
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your current TF code and why it does not work? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

**max_retries** is an optional parameter which set maximum number of times to retry this job if it fails.

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "bidb-cdc-data-load-glue-job" {
  name     = "bidb-cdc-data-load-glue-job"
  role_arn = var.glue_s3_redshift_access_role
  connections = [ "bidb-dev-datawarehouse-core-redshift-glue-connection" ]
  default_arguments = {
    "--Secret" = var.redshift_credentials_parameter_store
      }
  max_retries=1 }
```

Comment: Please format the code block properly, you are missing a couple of closing curly braces.

Comment: i configured that max_retries to 3 in the code. but i need to pass, if the glue job is trying first failed retry then it needs be send attempt number 1 as parameter to inside of glue job code